# how to use utcNow() in tags object type for ARM templates

Tags: json, azure, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

I am using utcNow() in resource tags, But instead of getting the date and time, am getting the "[utcNow()]" only again. Below is the format am using it Arm template.

ARM Template parameters:

```
"resourceTags": {
      "type": "object"
    }
```

parameters.json value:

```
"resourceTags": {
      "value": {
        "criticality": "Tier1",
        "applicationName": "Devzone",
        "owner": "abcd",
        "costCenter": "1234",
        "contactEmail": "abcd@gmail.com",
        "dataClassification": "Confidential",
        "environment": "Dev",
        "CreatedDate": "[utcNow()]"
      }
    }
```

I tried to use in the pipeline variable groups. Still am getting the same `"[utcNow()]"` instead of value.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get `utcNow()` substituted?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You can format code and data by selecting lines and pressing Ctrl+K). Don't include inappropriate tags (`yaml`) and  don't beg (`Please`), instead keep your questions crisp and spent your time to learn to format them.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-date#utcnow), you can only use the `utcNow()` function as the default value for a parameter.

> The function isn't allowed in other parts of the template because it returns a different value each time it's called. Deploying the same template with the same parameters wouldn't reliably produce the same results.

Here's what that would look like given your object

```json
"resourceTags": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue" : {
        "criticality": "Tier1",
        "applicationName": "Devzone",
        "owner": "abcd",
        "costCenter": "1234",
        "contactEmail": "abcd@gmail.com",
        "dataClassification": "Confidential",
        "environment": "Dev",
        "CreatedDate": "[utcNow()]"
      }
    }
```

The entire object will be overwritten if you supply a value for the parameter, though. So instead of setting it there, you'll need to separate the values of the object into individual parameters. For the CreatedDate parameter, set the default value *there* instead and don't supply the value in the pipeline. Then set the tag as the parameter.

```
"CreatedDate": "[parameters('utcNow')]"
```

Comment: Yes, The above documentation is good, But my task is to add resource tags into azure devops pipeline variable groups. Retrieve the value from there. Below is my variable group and I shared the ARm template above.
tags :  { "criticality": "Tier1","applicationName": "apps", "owner": "abcd",  "costCenter": "1234", "contactEmail": "abcd@abc.com", "dataClassification": "Confidential", "environment": "Dev", "createdDate": "[utcNow()]"}.

I must call the variable values into pipeline and those should be deployed on resources tags. How to use the utcNow() in object. Pls help me in this.

Comment: What is executing the ARM template? If it’s powershell, could you set the value in there?

Comment: Am using this in yaml pipeline. Am trying to get the whole value from variable group. Everything is fine except the value of utcNow(). How can I use utcNow() in Object type.

Comment: You can only use it in the `defaultValue` on your parameters file.

Comment: AM using the parameters file for passing the value of tags. How can I combine the resource tags parameters with utcNow() parameters on Tags properties. Pls someone guide me

Comment: I updated to show what the parameters would look like with a default value. I don't think you will be able to do this without separating the values of the properties into separate variables and then combine them into an object in the variables in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps and I got the results what I want

```
    "utcShort ": {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultValue": "[utcNow()]"
    },
    "resourceTags": {
    "type": "object"
  }
  },
  "variables":{
    "createdDate": {
    "createdDate": "[parameters('utcShort ')]"
    }
  },
```

Use this variable in Tags like below..

```
"tags": "[union(parameters('resourceTags'), variables('createdDate'))]"
```

This works for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I also find other way to achieve this. Pls find the below json.

```
    {
     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
    "tagValues": {
    "type": "object",
    "defaultValue": {
    "Dept": "Finance",
    "Environment": "Production"
    }
  }
  },
   "variables" : {
 "customTag" : {"myExtraDifferentTag": "myDifferentTagValue", 
"myAnotherExtraDifferentTag": "myAnotherDifferentTagValue"}
  },
"resources": [
  {
   "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
  "name": "[concat('storage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": "[union(parameters('tagValues'),json('{\"myExtraTag\":\"myTagValue \"}'))]",  //Concatenates `tagValues` object to inline object    
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard_LRS"
  },
  "kind": "Storage",
  "properties": {}
  }
   {
      "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "name": "mySecondResource",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": "[union(parameters('tagValues'),variables('customTag'))]",     //Concatenates `tagValues` object to `customTag` object
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "Storage",
      "properties": {}
    }
]
 }
```